# Email in Redmine 2.2 on Debian Wheezy : getaddrinfo: Name or service not known

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, debian, redmine

I've installed Redmine 2.2.2 on Debian Wheezy and when I try to send a test e-mail from the configuration panel, I always get the `getaddrinfo: Name or service not known` error message.

Apparently I'm not the only one having this error but everything I've tried has failed so far

Change access rights of sys files

```
sudo chmod o+r /etc/resolv.conf
sudo chmod o+r /etc/hosts
```

Change the email.yml config. I've tried

```
production:
  delivery_method: :sendmail
```

and I've also tried

```
production:
    delivery_mthod: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
        address: localhost
        port: 25
```

With no success (and I restart Apache every time I change a setting)

FYI, I can send e-mail with the server command line. This works fine :

```
$ echo "It works !" | mail -s "test" me@myself.com
```

Is there something else I should try ? Thanks in advance

PS : my Redmine environment is

```
Environment:
  Redmine version                          2.2.2.stable.11348
  Ruby version                             1.9.3 (x86_64-linux)
  Rails version                            3.2.11
  Environment                              production
  Database adapter                         Mysql2
Redmine plugins:
  no plugin installed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, problem solved. It was [quite stupid](http://jimmysintension.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/homer-doh.jpg) : the configuration file I was endlessly editing (`email.yml`) was overrided by `configuration.yml`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 also check your /etc/hosts file
I remember to experience a similar issue using localhost

Regards

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I've tried changing localhost to "127.0.0.1" but I still get the same error message